# Проблема с объектами в JavaScript (TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined)

Tags: javascript, объекты

Функция:

```
module.exports = function (date) {
     td = new Date(date);
     console.log(td.toLocaleString());

    var dt = {
        today: td,

        add: function add() {
            return this.today;

        },

        subtract: function subtract() {
            return this.today;                        
        },

     };

};
```

Использование функции:

```
 var time = date('2017-05-16 13:45')
        .add(24,'hours')
        .subtract(1, 'months')
        .add(3, 'days')
        .add(15, 'minutes');

assert.deepEqual(
    time.value,
    '2017-04-20 14:00'
);
```

В результате выходит это:

```
C:\Users\inikulin\Desktop\JS\неделя3\checks.js:8
    .add(24,'hours')
    ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined
```

Я понимаю,что программа недобита, но все же функция add даже не видна. в чем дело?

Comment: как вариант, есть такое решение:
после объекта вставить 
return dt;
но мне необходим возврат dt.today, что он не может и пишет туже самую ошибку

Comment: _функция add даже не видна. в чем дело?_ в том, что у тебя функция **ничего не возвращает**

Answer (score 1):

На данный момент, экспортируемая функция ничего не возвращает, так как в ней отсутствует оператор `return`.

В связи с этим при вызове `var time = date('2017-05-16 13:45')` в переменную `time` запишется значение `undefined` и все последующие попытки обращения к свойствам приведут к ошибке.

Для решения нужно вернуть что-то из этой функции.

Судя по предполагаемому использованию, возвращать нужно объект, который на данный момент сохраняется в переменную `dt`.

Далее, для решения основной задачи и организации *fluent*-интерфейса методы участвующие в цепочке вызовов должны возвращать тот же самый объект.